# CLLocation Public API for MVC principles

Tags: swift, model-view-controller, cllocation

I have written a class for CLLocation in Swift. In the view controller code I want to be able to call this class. So the classes are not in the view controller code, trying to make my code reusable..

Here is my code for the CLLocation class in swift :

```
class LocationClass : NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate
{
    var LocationManager : CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.LocationManager.delegate = self
        self.LocationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        println("didChangeAuthorizationStatus")

        switch status {
        case .NotDetermined:
            println(".NotDetermined")
            break

        case .AuthorizedWhenInUse:
            println(".Authorized")
            LocationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            break

        case .Denied:
            println(".Denied")
            break

        default:
            println("Unhandled authorization status")
            break

        }

    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

        let location = locations.last as! CLLocation

        println(location.coordinate.latitude)
        println(location.coordinate.longitude)



    }
}
```

from within an @IBOutlet in the View Controller I want to at least bring the pop up asking for authorisation and I want to return the didUpdateLocations so I can put the lat/long on the screen.

I can write it all without MVC, but this is bad practice.. Can anyone help me with this ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I added the variable as an instance variable (at the top of the view controller class), like this and it worked :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let LocManager = LocationClass()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var getlocation = LocationClass()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func LocButton(sender: UIButton) {

        LocManager.findUserLocation()



    }
}
```